# On Xcode 4.3.1 4E1019, Launch screen (Default.png, etc) has white line (1 pt tall) at bottom of image on launch

Tags: ios, sdk, launch, default.png

This is odd.  I have a Default.png, Default-Landscape.png, Default-Portrait.png and Default@2x.png.

The normal "default screen zoom animation" is where the Default.png zooms from the center of the screen out "into" place. This happens with all apps on iOS so this is the time when you can really see that white-line on the bottom of the "Default" image. It is a 1 pt (or so) line, going from left-to-right at the bottom of all my Default.png's (Default@2x.png, Default-Landscape.png, etc)... It occurs on both of my devices: "iPhone 4" and "iPad 1".  It does NOT occur on any of the simulators.

The images have not changed between my builds. Indeed, last week I built an earlier version (with the same launch graphics) and this did not happen.

The images are the correct size. I even changed the .ipa to a .zip, uncompressed and looked in the package.  The pngs are the correct size, so nothing killed that.

When I revert back to the AdHoc from the last build of my app, the issue goes away.  When I move to the current build, the issue comes back.

Any ideas?

BTW: Addendum: I grabbed my old source code (for the version that is okay), compiled with Xcode 4.3.1 and have the same issue.  white line on the bottom of the launch screen.

**Addendum**

Okay, well one thing we noticed:

Our PNGs for ipad were 1024x768 and 768x1024 instead of 1004x768 and 748x1024

We fixed that (weird that they worked before) and iPad launch was fixed and displays properly.  iPhone is still broken.

the iOS Human Interface Guidelines/ Custom Icon and Image Creation Guidelines says iPhone are supposed to be 320x480 and 640x960

I must've gotten confused when i originally created iPad graphics, but they have been working up until XCode 4.3.1!!! (2 years!) I know my iPad sizes were off, but wonder what made XCode change this and decide they were borked now?

Comment: I don’t understand your second paragraph. Is a splash screen animation occurring with Default.png after launch?

Comment: Ah yes I see, before the app has filled the entire screen. What about the status bar-is it interfering with the dimensions of your image? How about clean build and fresh install?

Comment: AND when the app finishes...there is still the white bar at the bottom.  Fresh build is the same.

Comment: Have you tried posting and search the [dev forums](http://devforums.apple.com)? Maybe someone else has this issue or a Springboard engineer can help.

Comment: Use your source control system to start with the last known good build, then do a binary search to find where it went wrong. If you make small checkins to your source control system it should be fairly easy to find which commit this started happening with. Once you know that revert all the files back to the working state and then update them one by one to see which file caused the problem.

Comment: Problem is, it was xCode that broke it...because compiling the last known good source with current Xcode breaks it.  read my addendum on this above.  I am still having issues with iPhone.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is the same issue as:
[iOS 5.1 : -[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:] background color draws solid black](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9609688/ios-5-1-uicolor-colorwithpatternimage-background-color-draws-solid-black/9609860#9609860)

Basically: iOS 5.1 fails to decode the last line of pixels in an indexed-color PNG (PNG8) or any grayscale PNG.

The workaround is to use PNG32, or add dummy lines to the end of the PNG8.

I filed a bug with Apple (#11069678) and advise you to do the same :)

Comment: THANK YOU!  :)  I will go file a bug too!

Comment: PNG32 happens to be quite large, especially for retina graphics. My indexed PNG went from approx 450kb to 1.1mb just trying to solve this bug :-s

Comment: However when I was playing around with PNG settings I solved the bug when I used a color matte. very strange but it worked.
But when I went back to indexed png without a matte I expected to see the bug again but it was gone!?
I've never been able to reproduce this bug and I now have a nice 450kb indexed PNG.

Any ideas what happened here?

Comment: What program are you exporting the PNG from?  The bottom line isnt always white, but will be a solid color.  I don't know what the root cause of the bug is, but I would love to find a better workaround :)  Right now im using png8 for my Default screenshots (with the line) and png32 elsewhere

Answer (score 0):

Photoshop users:

- Use the Image menu to change the mode to RGB.
- Then use the Image menu to switch to 16 Bits/Channel.