# colorWithPatternImage not working in io6?

Tags: ios, ios7, ios6, uicolor

I'm using *`colorWithPatternImage`* to change text color of `UITextView`. Its working fine in IO7 but not working in IO6.

Here is my Code :-

```
text.textColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ColorName.png"]];
```

Comment: Define "not working".

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9609688/ios-5-1-uicolor-colorwithpatternimage-background-color-draws-solid-black

Comment: its about text background i want it on textColor.

Comment: can you add your iOS 7 output?

Comment: It just set clear color to text.

Comment: Check what is return value for `[UIImage imageNamed:@"ColorName.png"]` in OS6

Comment: It's : <UIImage: 0x1d5a88d0>

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The internals of `UITextView` changed hugely between iOS 6 and 7.  Before iOS7, UITextView didn't support pattern colours for the text colour.  Several components gained support for pattern colours in iOS 7, and `UITextView` was one of them.

Comment: colorWithPatternImage is work with UITextView backgroundColor but not working with textColor.

Comment: Yes - a lot of components supported pattern colours for backgroundColor, but they didn't gain support for them as foreground colours until iOS 7.

Comment: Is there any alternative for it ??

Comment: None that I know of.  You might be able to do something by overriding `drawRect:` and drawing the text yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, `colorWithPatternImage` is not fit for your purposes in iOS 6. I would go for a solution that uses the text of the `UITextView` as a mask. Check the answer by David to this question: [Transparent UILabel textColor on superview.superview (sort of)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19787238/transparent-uilabel-textcolor-on-superview-superview-sort-of). He makes a path from the string he wants to see through and creates a mask out of it. For completeness check also [iOS UIView subclass, draw see-through text to background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17817378/ios-uiview-subclass-draw-see-through-text-to-background).

Hope this helps

EDIT

Turns out it was not so easy to achieve the masking effect you are after with a UITextView in iOS 6. I have only managed to "emulate" the look of UITextView by doing the following to a UIView:

```
UIView *tView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];

tView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"pattern.jpg"]];

NSString *text = @"Lorem ipsum...";

CATextLayer *mask = [CATextLayer layer];

mask.frame = frame;

mask.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0 alpha:0].CGColor;
mask.foregroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0 alpha:1].CGColor;
mask.string = text;
mask.wrapped = YES;
mask.fontSize = 25;

tView.layer.mask = mask;

[self.view addSubview:tView];
```

Here is a sample image from that view

[image]

To have this view scrolling you would need to place it inside a UIScrollView.

```
UIScrollView *scroll = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
// Setup tView as above
[scroll addSubview:tView];
[self.view addSubview:scroll];
```

If you follow this route you would need to play around with the scroll view and tView so that they look and behave like a UITextView.

Comment: yes it can apply to UILable as per that ans but not to UITextView.I want to apply this in textColor.